# How to profile my web application under mono/xsp?

Tags: performance, mono, profiling, profiler, xsp

So I have an ASP.Net web application that runs under mono/xsp4 (in development, anyway). How can I profile my web app to see what is causing it to be slow?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your specific environment and programming language, if you have "standard" web logs which contain:

> - Accessed URLs and
> - Elapsed response times on them

you may be able to use the generic & platform/language independent approach outlined in this SO question I posted yesterday:

[Profiling a multi-tiered, distributed, web application (server side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178903/profiling-a-multi-tiered-distributed-web-application-server-side)

Comment: I ended up using the Mono Profiler attached to xsp: http://www.mono-project.com/Profiler